# Set Tkinter label texts as elements of list

Tags: python, tkinter

I am building a gui that takes a `query` from a user and runs `leFunction.aFunction(query)` to return a list called `Result`. When the user presses enter, I want the text on each label to be set to an element of `Result`. My attempt, shown below, only prints out the last element of `Result` on the last label...(bear with me, I am a beginner with Tkinter.)

Thank you.

```
import Tkinter
import os
import leFunction

class simpleapp_tk(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

     def initialize(self):
        self.grid()

        self.entryVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self,textvariable=self.entryVariable)
        self.entry.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='EW')
        self.entry.bind("<Return>", self.OnPressEnter)
        self.entryVariable.set(u"")

        for j in range (1,10):
            self.labelVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
            label = Tkinter.Label(self,textvariable=self.labelVariable,
                              anchor="w",fg="black",bg="white")

            label.bind("<1>", lambda event, text="text": \
                          self.click_link(event, text))

            label.grid(column=0,row=j,columnspan=2,sticky='EW')


            self.labelVariable.set(j)

        self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.resizable(True,False)
        self.update()
        self.geometry(self.geometry())       
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)

    def OnPressEnter(self,event):
        #Result is a list
        Result = leFunction.aFunction(self.entryVariable.get())

        for i in range (0,len(Result)):
            print "result",i,":",Result[i]
            self.labelVariable.set(Result[i])
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)

    def click_link(self, event, text):
        print "you clicked '%s'" % text
        #os.system("open "+file)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = simpleapp_tk(None)
    app.title('my application')
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works (provided your `aFunction` code works as expected):

```
import Tkinter
import os
import leFunction

class simpleapp_tk(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()

        self.entryVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self,textvariable=self.entryVariable)
        self.entry.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='EW')
        self.entry.bind("<Return>", self.OnPressEnter)
        self.entryVariable.set(u"")

        self.labelVars = []
        for j in range (1,10):
            labelVar = Tkinter.StringVar()
            labelVar.set(j)
            self.labelVars.append(labelVar)
            label = Tkinter.Label(self,textvariable=labelVar,
                              anchor="w",fg="black",bg="white")

            label.bind("<1>", lambda event, text="sup": \
                          self.click_link(event, text))

            label.grid(column=0,row=j,columnspan=2,sticky='EW')

        self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.resizable(True,False)
        self.update()
        self.geometry(self.geometry())
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)

    def OnPressEnter(self,event):
        #Result is a list
        Result = leFunction.aFunction(self.entryVariable.get())

        for i in range (0,len(Result)):
            print "result",i,":",Result[i]
            self.labelVars[i].set(Result[i])
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)

    def click_link(self, event, text):
        print "you clicked '%s'" % text
        #os.system("open "+file)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = simpleapp_tk(None)
    app.title('my application')
    app.mainloop()
```

Instead of setting a `self.labelVariable` over and over, you now create a `self.labelVars` list, each element corresponding to a `labelVar`.  You can then set the text of the elements of this list as I do with:

```
self.labelVars[i].set(Result[i])
```